# IsWindowsVersionOrGreater arguments for windows 11

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am writing code in C++ and I need to detect if I am on Windows 11.
IsWindowsVersionOrGreater is an API I got that is to detects windows versions.

[LINK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/versionhelpers/nf-versionhelpers-iswindowsversionorgreater)

```
VERSIONHELPERAPI IsWindowsVersionOrGreater(
  WORD wMajorVersion,
  WORD wMinorVersion,
  WORD wServicePackMajor
);
```

What should be the argument to detect windows 11 from this API?

**Need:**

Windows 11 UI is different than Windows 10. Our code needs to detect windows 11 and use different UI elements and if it's below use different UI elements. We don't use windows UI elements directly but our own custom  UI elements. We need to detect wins 11 and then make conscious decisions based on that. Kindly help me detect if its win 11 –
Hence we need to detect.

Comment: Do you actually need to detect Windows 11 rather than availability of a specific API or feature?

Comment: Yes @IInspectable  , we need to detect if it's win 11 . Edited the question to include this information

Comment: @MAG: Sounds like you want to detect the availability of those different UI elements, not Windows 11. It's pretty safe to predict that like Windows 10, there will be many similar-but-not-identical versions of Windows 11. And on the flip side, Windows Server is not Windows 11 but may still have those UI elements.

Comment: We don't use windows UI elements directly but our own custom  UI elements .

Comment: we need to detect win 11 and then make concious decisions based on that . Kindly help me detect its win 11

Comment: use `RtlGetNtVersionNumbers` and if version >= *10.0.22000* this is win11 or higer

Comment: RtlGetNtVersionNumbers  api gave wrong build version   DWORD majorVersion = 0, minorVersion = 0, buildVersion = 0;

   typedef void (WINAPI* getver)(DWORD*, DWORD*, DWORD*);

   getver gv;

   gv = (getver)GetProcAddress(hm, "RtlGetNtVersionNumbers");

   if (gv)
   {

    gv(&majorVersion, &minorVersion, &buildVersion);

Comment: no, it always get correct. simply high 4 bits have - 'C' or 'F' in high nibble to indicate free/checked. look for this - https://pastebin.com/AuprPaEm and you not need use `GetProcAddress` - simply link with *ntdll.lib*

Comment: I know for Windows 10, some of those version detection functions require that the EXE that is running has a manifest indicating that it supports Windows 10. I assume it would be the same for Windows 11. Be sure the manifest has the requisite entries otherwise the version you detect might be Windows 7 or lower.

Comment: @JosephWillcoxson - depend from api. `RtlGetNtVersionNumbers` not require any manifest and always return real windows version

Comment: i searched more . Interestingly we need to do buildVersion &= 0xffff; to get the correct version . After this the version is correct .

Comment: @MAG also see [`RtlGetVersion()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nf-wdm-rtlgetversion)

Comment: @JosephWillcoxson except that there is no `supportedOS` guid defined for Windows 11, just continue using the Windows 10 guid: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68240304/

Comment: *Interestingly we need to do buildVersion &= 0xffff; to get the correct version* - more exactly `buildVersion &= 0x0fffffff`

Comment: without GetProcAddress  you wont be able tocall the function . What are you suggesting above @RbMm .. sorry missed that point about simply linking with ntdll will work

Comment: `RtlGetNtVersionNumbers` is exported by ntdll how minimum from xp and i sure that it will be exported alwaus, in any new windows version. as result we can use static linking.

Comment: why don't just use the standard UI frameworks from MS? That way the UI will automatically show properly on each OS

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect Windows 11 with .NET Framework or Windows API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69038560/detect-windows-11-with-net-framework-or-windows-api)