# How to detect Windows 11 programmatically?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I wonder if there's any API or way to detect if an application is running on Windows 11.

While searching I found these [apis](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/version-helper-apis) but it lack a specific for Windows 11, there's an `IsWindowsXXOrGreater` but I'm not sure which version to check and how to use it.

I also found some similar questions on StackOverflow but referring to Windows 10, I tried some of the answers but I still couldn't get a 'conclusive' way to check for it.

This show '10' when tested on Windows 11:

```cpp
    NTSTATUS(WINAPI *RtlGetVersion)(LPOSVERSIONINFOEXW);
    OSVERSIONINFOEXW osInfo;

    *(FARPROC*)&RtlGetVersion = GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleA("ntdll"), "RtlGetVersion");

    if (NULL != RtlGetVersion)
    {
        osInfo.dwOSVersionInfoSize = sizeof(osInfo);
        RtlGetVersion(&osInfo);
        qDebug() << "version: " << (double)osInfo.dwMajorVersion;

        MessageBoxA(NULL, std::to_string((double)osInfo.dwMajorVersion).c_str(), NULL, 0);
    }
```

Comment: [`IsWindowsVersionOrGreater`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/versionhelpers/nf-versionhelpers-iswindowsversionorgreater)? Listed in that link you provided.

Comment: @Daniela "*I also found some similar questions on StackOverflow but referring to Windows 10, I tried some of the answers but I still couldn't get a 'conclusive' way to check for it*" - really? There are **numerous** questions whose answers refer to specific APIs that can get the true Windows version, and there are plenty of those queations/answers referring to Windows 11 specifically. So, what *exactly* did you try that is not working for you?

Comment: Great thread here [IsWindowsVersionOrGreater is Useless](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2c7f9e1e-2fff-4c4f-80eb-9cd452468c90/iswindowsversionorgreater-is-useless?forum=windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues)

Comment: If the other answers failed, the app is probably missing the manifest file declarations as Remy Lebeau mentioned.  See VerifyVersionInfo remarks, Windows 10 section - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/Winbase/nf-winbase-verifyversioninfoa

Comment: The remarks section of many API calls includes some important warnings and limitations.  It's the "fine print" of the contract that takes away the promises of the large print   :)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude that function, and related functions, all lie in Windows 8.1 onward if the app is not manifested as supporting the specific Windows version being checked. Only a few APIs (namely NetServerGetInfo(), RtlGetVersion(), RtlGetNtVersionNumbers(), etc) tell the truth regardless of whether a manifest is present or not.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Note that there's no separate **supportedOS** manifest value for Windows 11.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I have added the API I have tested on Windows 11, what API did you mention that can get the true windows version?

Comment: @JonathanPotter right, and that is intentional on Microsoft's part: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68240304/ But, once you have access to a valid build number (via manifest or otherwise), you can differentiate between Win10 (< 21996) and Win11 (>= 21996).

Answer (score 2):

Windows 11 is an extension of Windows 10, so it does not increment the major/minor version numbers reported by `RtlGetVersion()` and other similar APIs, and does not add a new `<supportedOS>` guid in application manifests.

Windows 11 is still reported as v10.0, as shown in the [`OSVERSIONINFOEXW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/ns-wdm-_osversioninfoexw) documentation:

> The following table summarizes the version information that is returned by supported versions of Windows. **Use the information in the "Other" column or build number to distinguish between operating systems with identical version numbers.**
>
> | Operating system | Version number | dwMajorVersion | dwMinorVersion | Other |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | Windows 11 | 10.0 | 10 | 0 | wProductType == VER_NT_WORKSTATION |
> | Windows Server 2022 | 10.0 | 10 | 0 | wProductType != VER_NT_WORKSTATION |
> | Windows Server 2019 | 10.0 | 10 | 0 | wProductType != VER_NT_WORKSTATION |
> | Windows 10 (all releases) | 10.0 | 10 | 0 | wProductType == VER_NT_WORKSTATION |

So, you need to use the build number to differentiate between Windows 10 and 11.  Windows 11 is v10.0 build 21996 and higher.

Comment: `MessageBoxA(NULL, std::to_string((double)osInfo.dwBuildNumber).c_str(), NULL, 0);` prints 0 on my Win11 computer and on Win10 it prints a version,

Comment: @Daniela Why are you converting the number to a `double`? Just use it as-is, as `opeator<<` and `to_string()` have suitable overloads: `qDebug() << "version: " << osInfo.dwMajorVersion;` ... `std::to_string(osInfo.dwBuildNumber)`.

Comment: Still print 0 as `MessageBoxA(NULL, std::to_string(osInfo.dwBuildNumber).c_str(), NULL, 0);`

Comment: @Daniela Then there is something wrong with your setup, because Windows 11 is not v10.0.0. Maybe your `OSVERSIONINFOEXW` is using the wrong alignment? Are you declaring that struct type yourself in your own code, or are you using the definition provided in the Windows SDK?